# Why are there conflicting results for integration?

Tags: integration, calculator

Using my calculator, I had tried to evaluate the definite integral $$\int_{0}^{1}x^x \mathbf{d}x$$
However, according to my CASIO $fx-570$ES, the result was Math ERROR, which led me to believe that the definite integral does not exist at all, or was infinite.

In contrast, [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+1+x%5Ex) showed different results. Why do the results on both calculators differ? I cannot figure out a reason for the difference.

Comment: why would you trust either one when there are undefined quantities involved?

Comment: @WillJagy I assume you mean that $0^0$ is undefined?

Comment: yes, and you have no way of knowing how a machine deals with that. As it happens, the limit at $0^+$ of $x^x$ is $1,$ so this is actually a nice integral; just not formally nice.

Comment: @WillJagy In this context, I assume my calculator calculated $0^0$ as undefined, and in Wolframalpha's case, it calculated it as $1$.

Comment: If the numerical routine tries to actually compute $x^x$ at $x=0$ it will have a problem. Naively you would do this; WA presumably uses a more sophisticated algorithm that avoids this.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this is not about mathematics? And if so, where can my question be answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x^x$ for $x > 0$ and $f(0) = 1$ is well-defined, continuous, and bounded between $0.5$ and $1$ on the interval $[0, 1]$, so the integral does exist.

Whether it can be expressed in terms of "nice" constants is a rather different question; in particular, your calculator is likely unhappy with the (apparent but not actually existent) singularity at zero.

As far as computing the integral, you could simply integrate on $[0.1, 1]$ (guaranteed to be correct with an error at most $0.1$), $[0.001, 1]$ (guaranteed to have error at msot $0.001$), and so on; I'm sure that this will get rather close to the Wolfram Alpha result if you choose a small enough threshold.

As a fun fact, this is related is the so-called [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) which gives a series representation for the integral, roughly around $0.783$.

Comment: As a guess, I suppose that your calculator might be computing $$x^x = e^{x \log x}$$ via some sort of series or other representation; if so, it probably decides to quit as soon as it sees $\log 0$, even though $x \log x \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: A bit of an unrelated question: Why is it called Sophomore's dream?

Comment: The wikipedia article gives a reference to the name, relating it to the freshman's dream.